# React component (GeoJSON) not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, geojson, react-leaflet

I use the react-leaflet library to create a simple geoportal in which the user can change the color, visibility and transparency of the vector layers. I took the sliders to change the color from the React color collection. The problem is that after changing the style in the state of my component with GeoJSON, my vector layer does not change its color - it does not render again.

Here is my component with GeoJSON layer (there may be a few unnecessary elements that resulted from repeated attempts to fix the problem) :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';

class VectorLayers extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            key: this.props.layer.name,
            data: this.props.layer,
            style: {
                weight: 0,
                fillColor: this.props.color,
                fillOpacity: this.props.color,
                styleChanged: false
            },
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(this.state.style !== prevState.style) {
            let newStatus = !this.state.style.styleChanged
            this.setState({newStatus})
        }
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
        if(nextProps.color!==prevState.style.fillColor){
            return {style: {
                weight: 0,
                fillColor : nextProps.color,
                fillOpacity : nextProps.color
            }}
        }
        else return null;
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <GeoJSON
                key={ this.state.key }
                data={ this.state.data }
                style={ this.state.style }
            />
        );
    }
}

VectorLayers.propTypes = {
    layer: PropTypes.shape().isRequired,
    color: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default VectorLayers;
```

And this is a fragment of my App.js code with props for vector layer:

```
            {
                this.state.layers.map((layer) => ( 
                    this.state.checkboxes[layer.name] && (
                        <VectorLayers
                            key={ layer.name }
                            layer={ layer }
                            color={ this.state.colors[layer.name] }
                        />
                    )
                ))
            }
```

The function to change the color and the components with the sliders work well, so I do not see the need to add them here. I will be very grateful for your help in finding a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Change your style to a function like so:

`style={() => {return ({fillColor: this.state.style.fillColor})}}`

<s>Looks like the key you use never changes so react doesn't bother re-rendering your GeoJSON. Try something like</s>

`key={ this.state.key + this.state.style.fillColor }`

Also it's weird that you're assigning opacity a color like `fillOpacity: this.props.color,`

Shouldn't that be a number between 0 and 1?

Comment: A change in any of the props being passed in to `VectorLayers` should cause a re-render. e.g. if `color={ this.state.colors[layer.name] }` changes, then the component should re-render. By changing the `key` you're saying "this is an entirely new item". That component (and it's DOM elements) will be removed, and a new one inserted. That's very inefficient, and not necessary. Just imagine if you did that with a component near the root of your app, you'd be reloading almost the entire DOM just because a colour changed!

Comment: @AndyJ so, in your opinion, should I do what jbccollins proposes, or do you have any other option?

Comment: @jbccollins you have right about fillOpacity parameter, but the next feature I want to add will be the possibility to change the level of transparency, and the component that does it (from React Color Collection) accepts and returns the rgba format. FillOpacity can read an alpha channel from the rgba format, so instead of creating a function to convert rgba to a value of 0-1, I used the option provided by fillopacity - it was easier and it works well.

Comment: @AndyJ yeah you are right. That's less than ideal. A better option is to make the style prop a function:


```style={() => {return ({fillColor: this.state.style.fillColor})}}```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating that working: https://jsfiddle.net/23d8xg07/

Comment: @jbccollins I think that I understand what you mean. I will try to do it in my code, but if can I ask - what key should I use to make it correct if my previous way was wrong?

Comment: @MarekKania your key does not need to change. AndyJ is right about my suggestion to change the key being inefficient. Changing the style from an object to a function should be sufficient.

Comment: Great, it works perfectly! Thank you guys, @jbccollins you should add this solution as main answer to make it more visible.